# The matrix of 8 Term Error model in Vector Network Analyzer Calibration

Tags: matrix

My teacher gave me a matrix [image: 8 Term Error model], I do not understand it, not to mention to use it.

- What is the relationship between b0, T1,T2,T3,T4 and b1.
- The meaning of the "**cross**" the center matrix of T1/T2/T3/T4
- The two "**-**"s between ax and bx

I guess:

b0 = T1 x b1 ; b3 = T2 x b2; a0 = T3 x a1 ; a3 = T4 x a2

Comment: better fit at https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LvYa, You really need to spend a little more time on a 1st year semester class on linear algebra. The `cross` in the **T** matrix is just a partitioned [block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix). This is standard fare and is very important to learn about. It can be just notational convenience. But it is especially important when dealing with [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) methods. The lines in the vectors are just similarly helpful aids in thinking about the partitioned block matrix and how it relates to the operation there.

Comment: @LvYa, Get some book on the topic by Dr. Gilbert Strang. He writes pretty well and has spent a great deal of time teaching young students who very well may not take on much more than a little bit of applied mathematics in their lives. Because of his experience teaching classes of relatively average capability students, he's learned to teach the ideas very well to a very broad range of students. His books are usually excellent. He makes mistakes in his videos at MIT open courseware. But so do we all. (He just taught his last class, May of this year, and has finally retired at the age of 88!)

Answer (score 1):

If you google your exact question and take the first hit:

[Network Analyzer Error Models and Calibration Methods - Doug Rytting, Agilent](https://www.rfmentor.com/sites/default/files/NA_Error_Models_and_Cal_Methods.pdf)

you will find on page 23 the exact graphic you presented, along with detailed algebraic explanation.

Comment: The formula was snapshot from your link, but I do not know how to use the matrix, due to long time do not use linear algebra. Can you help me?

Comment: @LvYaojia It's not rocket science. See my comments above. If you want, you can go to this [MIT courseware site](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video_galleries/video-lectures/) and watch the lectures he gives. He will cover everything you likely need to know. He gets into block matrices quite early. I think somewhere by lecture 3, perhaps. Spend a few hours of your time and get familiar with the ideas and language. Especially pay attention to the ideas of columnspace, rowspace, and the two nullspaces, when time allows you.

Answer (score 0):

[In the matrix of 8 Term Error model page 23](https://www.rfmentor.com/sites/default/files/NA_Error_Models_and_Cal_Methods.pdf), thre is a matrix of 8 Term Error model. To simplify the math expression, some symbols are used.Those symbols are elements of block matrix and block matrix multiplication can be found in [Block matrix - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix).

I rewrite the matrix in more detail.

[image: expanded matrix]